# "Bookmark not valid" error in Access database

Tags: java, ms-access-2010, ucanaccess

I have a simple application that writes data from a MySQL database into an Access `.accdb` database.

I have used it for 4 months and I haven't had any problems.

Yesterday I tried to use it and now I have a problem. If I try to open the file with Microsoft Access and I try to open table `CodScontrini`, I see all the records. If I try to open `Scontrini` table I have this message:

> bookmark not valid

If I try to run my Java application from Eclipse I see this warning message:

> WARNING:Error in the metadata of the table CodScontrini: table's row count in the metadata is 665 but 499 records have been found and loaded by UCanAccess. All will work fine, but it's better to repair your database.

Comment: Have you tried Compact and Repair in your Access database?

Answer (score 1):

It means that a inconsistency between data and metadata has been detected in your access db. The Compact and Repair tool will solve this issue.

Comment: I open my file CassaGestionle.accdb with Microsoft Access 2010, then I go in File -> Info -> Compact and Restore, I have this message of error: (Unknow format of database C:\user\desktop\Cassagesionale.accdb)

Comment: @bircastri The two messages cited in the question may actually not be directly related. The second (metadata warning) message refers to the `CodScontrini` table and is usually not a serious issue. The first (invalid bookmark) message refers to the `Scontrini` table and often indicates corrupted data within that table. Try exporting the `Scontrini` table to CSV or Excel and see if you get all (or any) of the records out.

Comment: If I try to export table Scontrini in CSV or Excel file I have the same Error. Bookmark not valid.

Comment: @bircastri It is certainly starting to sound like that table (or perhaps one of its indexes) is corrupt. If you are unable to export the table to CSV from Access then perhaps try exporting it to CSV with Jackcess using code something like [this](http://pastebin.com/WmRDQNi3). (You can use that code in a UCanAccess project because UCanAccess uses Jackcess so the required libraries should already be in your build path.)